# Baking 0603 Components

Tags: surface-mount, production, reflow

I have a few 0603 LEDs that come with the instruction to bake them if they had the chance to draw moisture. What is the best way to do that?

1. Can I leave them in the tape, so I don't lose the orientation?
2. Alternatively, can I just run the entire board through a cycle with 24h at 50 degrees, followed by the normal reflow process?

Comment: How well will your solder paste reflow after 24 hours at 50° C?

Answer (score 1):

The reason to bake them is so they are not damaged during the solder reflow process. Running them through the oven after mounting them on the board would defeat the purpose.

If you are hand soldering, don't worry about baking them. They are not particularly more likely to be damaged due to moisture ingress than they would be due to the simple uncontrolled nature of hand soldering.

If you are reflowing then I would expect you can bake them in their tapes. Generally I've only heard of prebaking being done at professional assembly shops. At which the process of de-taping them and then re-taping them would be more expensive than simply discarding the parts and buying new ones.

Comment: How about gluing them to the board, then bake it before soldering?

Comment: @winny, I guess for wave solder. But for reflow you put down the solder paste before placing the parts.

Comment: Yes, wave solder was the word I was looking for. Should perhaps be a consideration if you know beforehand that you will buy components in large batches but not have continuous production so you might sit with old components?

Comment: @winny, Pro assembly shops should be able to re-pack parts after a run, sealing the bags under vacuum and with dessicant the same way the chip-makers packed them before shipping them to you.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I've only seen volume production so I'm just thinking out loud.